# Forcefully Exit application on encountering Force Close Error in android

Tags: android

Can somebody help me out in this?I want to exit my application completely when the user encounters a Force Close Error.Currently what happens is user has to  press ok buttons few times(2-3 times) on app crash.Dont know why  that happens.However i need help for exiting the application when Force Close error occurs.
I have seen some of the links that specifies to use System.exit(0);
However i dont want to kill my process manually but want to kill it only if Force close error occurs.Also found this but no help

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
// closing Entire Application
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: First of all you should not encounter force close in your application. Find that and try to resolve that.

Comment: Application force closes only when your code fails use try catch and find out why it fails and if you want to close application when there is an error call the system.exit() after catching the error

Comment: Yes I accept that but my questions asks something else --How can i identify that Force close error has occured and fire an event on its occurence.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to catch all the uncaught exceptions in your UncaughtExceptionHandler

Check the link for more info:
[Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler ex)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

As per the reference

> Sets the default uncaught exception handler. This handler is invoked in case any Thread dies due to an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0):

When the app encounters an exception it crashes and you see force close...So try to analyze when your app throws such an exception and use catch or finally to resolve that. And if you want to exit your app then call system.exit(0) or finish() inside catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix Android Force Close Error by going through the solutions given in the presentation tutorial
http://www.slideshare.net/StenaGlass/android-force-close-error-fix

I am hopeful that you will resolve your problem by folling the steps given in the presentation tutorial

Wish you best of luck.